# Remove children from parent Element

Tags: javascript, html

My Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet" as="style" media="all">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <a href="#">LINK</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="adv">
            <a href="#">LINK</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Web Test...!
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <a href="#">LINK</a>
    </footer>
    <script>
        $(".content head").remove();
        ...
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript:

```
<script>
    $("head").remove();
    $('header').remove();
    $('footer').remove();
    $('div.adv').remove();
    $('script').remove();
</script>
```

All of the following elements must be removed: "html", "head", "title", "meta", "body", "header", "footer", "main", "script" and "div.adv".

Only the following elements should not be removed:
"div.content"

Out:

```
<div class="content">
    Web Test...!
</div>
```

Comment: erm, if you remove html, body and main, where's the div going to live? and what does `Out:` mean? out where? perhaps you just want to put that div to `Out` rather than removing everything that contains it

Comment: It does not work. @the-fool

Comment: That's because you should for a start include the jQuery library. https://jquery.com/

Comment: Can you preview a project? @the-fool

Comment: @MaryamSadeq, once you have the html you need to do something with it. What is your actual goal here?

Comment: It takes the html, so you can use it somewhere. Doing what OP wants doesnt make sense. It wil destroy the page.

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript use [Element.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove):

```js
const ELS_toRemove = document.querySelectorAll('header, footer');  
ELS_toRemove.forEach(EL => EL.remove());
```

or to be fore specific with your selectors:

```
"body > header, body > footer"
```

If you want to re-append one Element (`.content`) whilst *removing* the contents of the other ones use also [Element.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append). Contrary to `.outerHTML` it will preserve all current data and Events of the moved Element.

```js
const EL_content = document.querySelector(".content");
const ELS_toRemove = document.querySelectorAll("body > *");

// Remove desired elements:
ELS_toRemove.forEach(EL => EL.remove());

// Add back .content
// .append() will preserve all current data and Events on that element
document.querySelector("body").append(EL_content);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Web Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet" as="style" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#">LINK</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="adv">
      <a href="#">LINK</a>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Web Test...!
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `JQuery` to your HTML code on `head`.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to put your code below the JQuery import:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("head").remove();
    $('header').remove();
    $('footer').remove();
    $('div.adv').remove();
    $('script').remove();
});
</script>
```